# How to track or predict path of already found contours using optical flow and motion vectors?

Tags: python, opencv

I am coding a project in OpenCV python. It is basically a traffic monitoring Final Year project.. Now i have coded so far that when run it identifies vehicles in a video and draws a rectangle and centroid on those vehicles. Now what i want to do is to draw motion vectors or track just the above found contours i.e the vehicles. I am unable to figure what will be the arguments in this case in opencv optical flow function.. Can anyone help me with that ? thanks .. this is the contour finding portion of code..

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                       cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    try: hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
    except: hierarchy = []


    #Drawing Rectangles arround contours (Vehicles)
    for contour, hier in zip(contours, hierarchy):
        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        if w > 8 and h > 8:

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do it using OpticalFlow. I would sugest you look into [`KalmanFilter`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d6a/classcv_1_1KalmanFilter.html#gsc.tab=0). With that you can track, smooth out and predict motion vectors from history.

Comment: okay, let me look into that and then i'll tell you if it worked in my case or not. Thanks for the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have done that before. You will need 2 frames. But you can do your process faster if you extract a sub-image that contains the 4 corners of the previous detected object and the 4 corners of that vehicle in the current frame, the rectangle should be as small as possible and it should match in both images. After that you can apply the optical flow function:

```
cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvsRgle,currentRgle,flow, 0.5, 3, 5, 5, 7, 1.5, 0);
```

Here are some useful links that you should visit: [1](http://study.marearts.com/2014/04/opencv-study-calcopticalflowfarneback.html), [2](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) and my favorite [3](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html)